# Error in moq "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

While trying to MOCK AWS Cognito Signup Method using `Moq` `C#`

```
 public async void Signup(UserTO user)
    {

        var req = new SignUpRequest()
        {

        };
        _cognito.Setup(m =>
            m.SignUpAsync(It.IsAny<SignUpRequest>())) // LOE
            .ReturnsAsync(() =>
            new SignUpResponse()
            {

            });
    }
```

But at the #LOE, getting the below error

> Error CS0854  An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

If I press f12 to get the definition of the SignUpAsync(), it looks as

```
Task<SignUpResponse> SignUpAsync(SignUpRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

**What's causing this error & how to get rid of this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mock expects the entire member definition to be configured/setup

Expect the options parameter using `It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()`

```
public async Task Signup(UserTO user) {

    var req = new SignUpRequest() {

    };
    _cognito.Setup(m =>
        m.SignUpAsync(It.IsAny<SignUpRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    )
    .ReturnsAsync(() => new SignUpResponse());

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Task<SignUpResponse> SignUpAsync(SignUpRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
> ```

cancellationToken argument is causing the error, you need to specify a CancellationToken  for the mock since using the default `default(CancellationToken)` value is not allowed.

Try

```
        _cognito.Setup(m =>
            m.SignUpAsync(It.IsAny<SignUpRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken >())) // LOE
            .ReturnsAsync(() =>
            new SignUpResponse()
            {

            });
```